# How to find groups logically equivalent concepts using Pellet?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api, pellet

In fact, I make an ontology defined on OWL2 language using java prgramation with OWL API. I integrate the required jar in my project to use the inference engine Pellet. My question is how I detect in my ontology groups of concepts that are logically equivalent? 
here the code which I use Pellet.

```
 import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.StreamDocumentTarget;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNamedIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyChange;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyStorageException;
import com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasoner;
import com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasonerFactory;
import org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase;







/**
 *
 * @author hela
 */
public class Owl {

  public  void createNewOnto(List<String[][]> cps, LinkedList<Map<String, String>> rel, String uri ) throws OWLOntologyCreationException,
        OWLOntologyStorageException {
     OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
        IRI iri = IRI.create("http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/Annot2Onto.owl");
        OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology(iri); 

OWLObjectProperty subTopicOf =factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(iri+"/#sub-topicOf"));
OWLObjectProperty kindOf =factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(iri+"/#kindOf"));
OWLClass thing = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(iri+"/#OWLThing"));
  manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(thing));
 Set<OWLAxiom> genders = new HashSet<OWLAxiom>();
 for(Map<String, String> rmp : rel){
     Set<OWLNamedIndividual> classes =ontology.getIndividualsInSignature();
  List< OWLNamedIndividual> listc = new ArrayList(classes);
   IRI ir = IRI.create(iri+"/#"+rmp.get("concept1"));
    OWLNamedIndividual c1=null;

 if(ontology.containsClassInSignature(ir)){
     int i=0;

     while(i<listc.size()&& c1==null){
         if(listc.get(i).toString().compareTo("<"+ir.toString()+">")==0){
             c1=listc.get(i);

              manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(c1));
             manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(thing, c1));
         }


         i++;
     }
 }

 else {
      c1 = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(iri+"/#"+rmp.get("concept1")));

        //manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(c1));
        manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(thing, c1));
 }

 IRI ir2 = IRI.create(iri+"/#"+rmp.get("concept2"));
    OWLNamedIndividual c2=null;
 if(ontology.containsIndividualInSignature(ir2)){
     int i=0;

     while(i<listc.size()&& c2==null){

         if(listc.get(i).toString().compareTo("<"+ir2.toString()+">")==0){
             c2=listc.get(i);
              System.out.println("concept2 = "+c2.toString());
             manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(c2));
               manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(thing, c2));
         }
         i++;
     }
 }

 else{ 
      c2 = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(iri+"/#"+rmp.get("concept2")));

       //manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(c2));
        manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(thing, c2));
 }

if(rmp.get("relation").compareTo("kind of")==0){
//domainAxiom = factory.getOWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom(sorteDe,c1);
//rangeAxiom = factory.getOWLObjectPropertyRangeAxiom(sorteDe,c2);

genders.add(factory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(kindOf, c1,
                c2));
}

else{

  genders.add(factory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(subTopicOf, c1,c2));


}

    String[][] cp1 = this.getConcept(cps,rmp.get("concept1"));
    String[][] cp2 = this.getConcept(cps,rmp.get("concept2") );
    cps.remove(cp2);
    cps.remove(cp1);
    // Now we apply the change using the manager.
    //manager.applyChange(addAxiom1);
 }
    List<OWLOntologyChange> la=manager.addAxioms(ontology, genders);
    manager.applyChanges(la);

for(String[][] ct: cps){
    OWLNamedIndividual res=factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(iri+"/#"+ct[0][0]));
       manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(res));
      manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(thing, res));

}

File file = new File(uri+"/Annot2Onto.owl");
PelletReasoner reasoner = PelletReasonerFactory.getInstance().createNonBufferingReasoner( ontology );
      manager.addOntologyChangeListener( reasoner );
reasoner.flush();
System.out.println(reasoner.isConsistent());
KnowledgeBase kb = reasoner.getKB();
kb.get
    manager.saveOntology(ontology, IRI.create(file.toURI()));
    manager.saveOntology(ontology, new StreamDocumentTarget(System.out));

}
  public String[][] getConcept(List<String[][]> cps, String s){
      String[][] cp =null;
      int i=0;
      while((i<cps.size()) && (cp==null) ){
          if(cps.get(i)[0][0].compareTo(s)==0)
              cp=cps.get(i);
      i++;
      }
      return cp;
  }
```

I need the java code for Pellet that allows to detect groups logically equivalent concepts. I will be grateful for your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Joshua Taylor thank you. Yes I'm asking how to detect x and y using Pellet which x and y are logically equivalent. I mean by logically that in my ontology I don't have this code "x owl:equivalentClass y"

Comment: RIght, but Pellet will be inferring those triples for you.  If you've got an OntClass, you could list the equivalent classes, and if you've just got InfModel, you could listStatements with the property `owl:equivalentClass`.

Comment: Ok, but in my ontology I have just one class and the others are NamedIndividual. How coul I detect which NamedIndividual are logically equivalent?

Comment: You asked about *concepts*.  Individuals aren't concepts.  Classes are *concepts*.  The same principle would apply, though;  you'd just be looking for triples with the predicate `owl:sameAs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OWLAPI, all results from `OWLReasoner` that are of type `Node` and `NodeSet` consist of sets of equivalent entities.

For `OWLNamedIndividual`, `OWLReasoner::getSameIndividuals()` returns a `Node<OWLNamedIndividual>` object, which contains all individuals inferred to be `sameAs` each other.

It is also possible to ask for the instances of a class:
`OWLReasoner::getInstances()` will return a `NodeSet<OWLIndividual>`, which is a collection of  `Node` objects, each corresponding to a set of `OWLNamedIndividual` objects that are also `sameAs` each other.

The same applies to sub/super/equivalent classes and properties.

Edit to include comments:

To get all named individuals in an ontology, grouped by sameAs in equivalence classes, an approach is to ask for all instances of `owl:Thing`

`NodeSet<OWLNamedIndividual> individuals = reasoner.getInstances(dataFactory.getOWLThing(), false);`

A NodeSet contains Nodes (in no particular order); each Node contains `OWLNamedIndividual` objects, in no particular order. All individuals in the same node are sameAs each other, i.e., each one can be considered a representative for its equivalence class. There is no notion of a canonical representative.

Similarly, to get all classes of equivalence for `OWLClass`

`NodeSet<OWLClass> classes = reasoner.getSubClasses(dataFactory.getOWLThing(), false);`

This is a collection of `Node<OWLClass>`, each of which contains equivalent classes. The order in which the Nodes are found in the NodeSet, and the order of the OWLClasses in a Node, play no role and might change from one call to the next.

From the `OWLReasoner` [javadoc](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_3_5_0/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/OWLReasoner.html)

Nodes
The reasoner interface contains methods that return `NodeSet` objects. These are sets of `Node` objects. A Node contains entities. 
For a `Node<OWLClass>` of classes, each class in the node is equivalent to the other classes in the Node with respect to the imports closure of the root ontology. 
For a `Node<OWLObjectProperty>` of object properties, each object property in the Node is equivalent to the other object properties in the node with respect to the imports closure of the root ontology. 
For a Node of data properties, each data property in the Node is equivalent to the other data properties in the node with respect to the imports closure of the root ontology. 
For a Node of named individuals, each individual in the node is the same as the other individuals in the node with respect to the imports closure of the root ontology.

Comment: This would require having a particular individual in mind first, though, and asking "what's equal to it"?  If you wanted to iterate over the equivalence classes, is there easy way to do that?  (Yes, one could iterate over individuals, and then over same individuals, shortcutting the first step if an individual'd already been seen as a same individual.)

Comment: No direct access in the OWLReasoner interface, but a trick would be to ask for direct and indirect instances of OWL:Thing. This should return all individuals neatly sorted in equivalence classes.

Comment: You mean that instances will be ordered by equivalence class?  (This is interesting, I didn't know this.  Is it reliable/specified behavior?)

Comment: Not ordered, but grouped by equivalence class. A Node is basically another name for that. I'm not sure how it's specified but it's supposed to be reliable - it's the reasoner responsibility to build the nodes, so mileage may vary.

Comment: Sorry, 'ordered' was the wrong term there.  You mean that if we have a, b, c, d, e, where a = b = c and d = e, we'll get a representative from {a b c} and a representative from {d e}, or we'll get a listing of all them, and {a b c} will appear consecutively (but with no particular order) and {d e} will appear consecutivy (but with no particular order)?

Comment: I'll amend the answer

Comment: Excellent explanation!  I didn't catch the Node/Individual distinction at first (and I'm not sure whether I knew about it to begin with).  It looks very handy.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: The approach in this answer is OK, but it's based on the mistaken assumption that the Jena API was being used (not much code was shown in the original version of the question).*

This is really more of a question about how to use Jena's API for working with models, since Pellet can be used with other APIs (e.g, the OWLAPI) and how you'd retrieve this information will be different in those cases.  The code you've shown so far, though, appears to be using Jena.  The main approaches to consider here are:

- listing all pairs of equivalent classes
- for some particular class, list all the equivalent classes

The code below shows how to do both.  Note that it's not strictly correct to say that you're listing *all* equivalent classes, because  there are infinitely many of those.  E.g.,

A ≡ A ⊓ ⊤ ≡ A ⊔ ⊥ ≡ A ⊓ A ⊓ ⊤

Strictly speaking, those are *class expressions*, and that's what there can be more than one of.  Once you've determined, e.g., A ≡ B, there's really just one *class*, there just happen to be two class expressions that denote that class.  It's sort of like asking, "what numbers are equal to 2?"  The answer is "only 2", whereas to the question "what arithmetic expressions have the value 2?"  the answer to that is {2, 1+1, 2 ×1, 4/2, …}.  I only point this out because  I'm not sure which results Pellet will give you, though I expect that it will just look for class expressions that are already present in your ontology.

```java
import org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.OWL;

public class GetEquivalentClassesExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Create an OntModel with an attached Pellet reasoner.
         */
        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC );

        /*
         * Load your data.
         */
        model.read( "..." );

        /*
         * To list all pairs of equivalent classes, you can just list
         * the statements with the property owl:equivalentClass
         */
        StmtIterator s = model.listStatements( null, OWL.equivalentClass, (RDFNode) null );
        while ( s.hasNext() ) { 
            System.out.println( s.next() );
        }

        /*
         * If you just want the classes that are equivalent to some particular
         * class, you can get a reference to that class, and then ask for its
         * equivalent classes.
         */
        OntClass klass = model.getOntClass( "..." );
        ExtendedIterator<OntClass> c = klass.listEquivalentClasses();
        while ( c.hasNext() ) {
            System.out.println( c.next() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I'm using OWL API for creating my ontology. Morever all concept are declared as NamedIndividual cause I have ObjectProperty which must declared with multiple domain and range and it's only allowed for individual. To be more clear I have edited my question to share with you the code which I create the ontology and use PelletReasoner. As result I want a method de detect all logically Equivalent NamedIndividual.

Comment: I wish you'd made it clearer which API you were using in the original question, and that you were working with NamedIndividuals.  It's still not too hard to list equal individuals with the OWLAPI, though.  It should be a matter of asking for same individual axioms…  I might get to come back to this in a while…

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will be grateful if you could guide how to list logically  equal NamedIndividual. Thanks in advance